# RMarkdown: Two column text overlaps with titles

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I'm writing an article on RMarkdown with the [svmiller](https://github.com/svmiller/svm-r-markdown-templates/blob/master/article-example/svm-rmarkdown-article-example.pdf) template and I want it to be two column, so this is now my YAML:

```
---
output: 
  stevetemplates::article:
    fig_caption: true
  pandoc_args: [
      "-V", "classoption=twocolumn"
    ]
title: "Nombre del artículo o informe"
author:
- name: Author Name
  affiliation: Affiliation
abstract: \textbf{Resumen } `r readLines('abstract.txt', encoding = 'UTF-8')`
keywords: "pandoc, r markdown, knitr"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
geometry: textwidth=170mm, textheight=235mm, footskip=12mm, voffset=10mm
fontfamily: mathpazo
fontsize: 11pt
endnote: no
header-includes:
- \hoffset = -2mm
- \setlength{\columnsep}{14mm}
classoption: twocolumn
---
```

But this is what I get:

[Rmd Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adLHc.png)

I'm new with Rmd and I don't know what to do.

I tried with `multicol` package but each section is in separate sub-file (`r child = 'chapterN.Rmd'`), also I tried with

```
header-includes:
- \twocolumn
- \setlength{\columnsep}{14mm}
```

without `classoption: twocolumn` and `pandoc_args` but its the same result.

Edit: Here's the .tex file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\newcommand*{\authorfont}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
\usepackage[]{mathpazo}


  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}




\usepackage{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{}    % clear the title
\renewcommand{\absnamepos}{empty} % originally center

\renewenvironment{abstract}
 {{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0mm}
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin}%
  }%
  \relax}
 {\endlist}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
%  \null
%  \vskip 2em%
%  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\raggedright  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} \@title \par}%
}
%\fi
\makeatother




\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}


\usepackage{graphicx,grffile}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}


\title{Nombre del artículo o informe  }



\author{\Large Author
Name\vspace{0.05in} \newline\normalsize\emph{Affiliation}  }


\date{}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\itshape}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\itshape}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\normalsize\itshape}
\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\normalsize\itshape}





\newtheorem{hypothesis}{Hypothesis}
\usepackage{setspace}


% set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %línea superior
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.8pt}%línea inferior
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{This is fancy header}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{And this is a fancy footer}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\hoffset = -2mm
\textwidth=170mm
\twocolumn
\setlength{\columnsep}{14mm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% move the hyperref stuff down here, after header-includes, to allow for - \usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{}{%
\ifxetex
  \PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage[setpagesize=false, % page size defined by xetex
              unicode=false, % unicode breaks when used with xetex
              xetex]{hyperref}
\else
  \PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage[draft,unicode=true]{hyperref}
\fi
}

\@ifpackageloaded{color}{
    \PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{color}
}{%
    \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
}
\makeatother
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true,
            bookmarks=true,
            pdfauthor={Author Name (Affiliation)},
             pdfkeywords = {pandoc, r markdown, knitr},
            pdftitle={Nombre del artículo o informe},
            colorlinks=true,
            citecolor=blue,
            urlcolor=blue,
            linkcolor=magenta,
            pdfborder={0 0 0}}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls

% Add an option for endnotes. -----


% add tightlist ----------
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}

% add some other packages ----------

% \usepackage{multicol}
% This should regulate where figures float
% See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned
\usepackage[section]{placeins}

% CSL environment change -----

\newlength{\cslhangindent}
\setlength{\cslhangindent}{1.5em}
\newlength{\csllabelwidth}
\setlength{\csllabelwidth}{3em}
\newenvironment{CSLReferences}[2] % #1 hanging-ident, #2 entry spacing
 {% don't indent paragraphs
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  % turn on hanging indent if param 1 is 1
  \ifodd #1 \everypar{\setlength{\hangindent}{\cslhangindent}}\ignorespaces\fi
  % set entry spacing
  \ifnum #2 > 0
  \setlength{\parskip}{#2\baselineskip}
  \fi
 }%
 {}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\CSLBlock}[1]{#1\hfill\break}
\newcommand{\CSLLeftMargin}[1]{\parbox[t]{\csllabelwidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\CSLRightInline}[1]{\parbox[t]{\linewidth - \csllabelwidth}{#1}\break}
\newcommand{\CSLIndent}[1]{\hspace{\cslhangindent}#1}

\begin{document}

% \pagenumbering{arabic}% resets `page` counter to 1
%
% \maketitle

{% \usefont{T1}{pnc}{m}{n}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\thispagestyle{plain}
{\fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\raggedright
\maketitle  % title \par

}

{
   \vskip 13.5pt\relax \normalsize\fontsize{11}{12}
\textbf{\authorfont Author
Name} \hskip 15pt \emph{\small Affiliation}   

}

}








\begin{abstract}

    \hbox{\vrule height .2pt width 39.14pc}

    \vskip 8.5pt % \small

\noindent \textbf{Resumen } El modelamiento de los prepagos es crucial para predecir potenciales pérdidas, debido a la incertidumbre de la duración real de los créditos. En este trabajo se construirá un modelo de regresión con estructura "ARMA" para el ajuste y generación de pronósticos basados principalmente en proyecciones futuras de las variables exógenas de tipo macroeconómicas consideras. Este modelo permitirá en el futuro generar escenarios y evaluar el impacto en la tasa de prepago de una entidad financiera.


\vskip 8.5pt \noindent \emph{Keywords}: pandoc, r markdown, knitr \par

    \hbox{\vrule height .2pt width 39.14pc}



\end{abstract}


\vskip -8.5pt


 % removetitleabstract

\noindent 

# Introducción

Content 

# Metodología

.
.
.

\singlespacing
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add the intermediate .tex file?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes! there it is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if this template does not properly set up `\maketitle` but adds most of the content manually. To work around this problem:

- use another template if you are not force to use that one (the code looks rather messy, loading packages in the wrong order, outdated packages ....)
- if you are really forced to use that one, you could forgo the `twocolumn` class option and instead use `\begin{multicols}{2}....\end{multicols}` around the body of your document:

---

```
---
output: 
  stevetemplates::article:
    fig_caption: true
title: "Nombre del artículo o informe"
author:
- name: Author Name
  affiliation: Affiliation
abstract: \textbf{Resumen } test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
keywords: "pandoc, r markdown, knitr"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
geometry: textwidth=170mm, textheight=235mm, footskip=12mm, voffset=10mm
fontfamily: mathpazo
fontsize: 11pt
endnote: no
header-includes:
  - \hoffset = -2mm
  - \usepackage{multicol}
  - \setlength{\columnsep}{14mm}
---
\begin{multicols}{2}%
\noindent test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
\end{multicols}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried using multicol package but I have this problem:

```
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode.
l.211 #
        Introducción 
```

Comment: @SoyNicolas Yes, the `#` in your .tex file are wrong. But you only show the header of your .rmd file and not the part responsible for the error, so hard to diagnose.

Comment: the `#` are for section titles (`# Chapter 1`) but my code has R chunks with outputs with `#`, like `# lm(y ~ x1 + x2)` so idk what to do

Comment: @SoyNicolas I think it would be best if you would ask a new question including a [mre] that actually reproduces this problem